# How can I rbind multiple single-value rows to my data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind, cbind

The following works as expected:

```r
A <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 3))
B <- data.frame(4, 5, 6)
cbind(A, B)
  c.1..2..3. X4 X5 X6
1          1  4  5  6
2          2  4  5  6
3          3  4  5  6
```

Now I am doing the transpose with `rbind`:

```r
At <- data.frame(1, 2, 3)
Bt <- data.frame(c(4, 5, 6))
rbind(At, Bt)
```

and this is not working:

> Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) :
> numbers of columns of arguments do not match

Interstingly, both `cbind` and `rbind` support the following:

```r
cbind(A, 4, 5, 6)
  c.1..2..3. 4 5 6
1          1 4 5 6
2          2 4 5 6
3          3 4 5 6

rbind(At, 4, 5, 6)
  X1 X2 X3
1  1  2  3
2  4  4  4
3  5  5  5
4  6  6  6
```

where the latter is what I am expecting from `rbind(At, Bt)`.

How can I get it?

*Edit2*: Some context: I have a large call `rbind(A1t, ..., B1t, A2t, ..., B2t, A3t)`, so I would prefer an answer which processes the `Bit` in a way such that I don't have to modify the sequence of parameters of `rbind`. (I would be fine with replacing `rbind` by an alternative.)

*Edit3*:
While I thought that the implementations `cbind` and `rbind`are 100% analogous, this is only true for `methods::cbind` and `methods::rbind`.

`methods::cbind`: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/79298c4/src/library/methods/R/cbind.R#L35-L125

`methods::rbind`: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/79298c4/src/library/methods/R/rbind.R#L24-L114

`base::cbind`: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/79298c4/src/main/bind.c#L1199

`base::rbind`: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/79298c4/src/main/bind.c#L1464

`cbind.data.frame`: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/79298c4/src/library/base/R/dataframe.R#L1259

`rbind.data.frame`: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/79298c4/src/library/base/R/dataframe.R#L1262

Answer (score 1):

You can use `do.call` to achieve the same output as `rbind(At, 4, 5, 6)`.

```
At <- data.frame(col1 = 1, col2 = 2, col3 = 3)
Bt <- data.frame(col1 = c(4, 5, 6))

do.call(function(...) rbind(At, ...), as.list(Bt$col1))

#  col1 col2 col3
#1    1    2    3
#2    4    4    4
#3    5    5    5
#4    6    6    6
```

Since the length of `Bt$col1` can be variable I have used `...` as argument to the function.

Comment: This is nice. However, I have one large `rbind` call with many rows, only few of which work as lists. Something like `rbind(A1t, Bt, A2t)`. Any way to unpack (this is what `do.call` does, right) only the `Bt` data frames inline?

Comment: Do you need `do.call(function(...) rbind(At, ..., A2t), as.list(Bt$col1))` ?

Comment: Nice idea - I'll try that! A more compact solution would be preferred, though :)

Comment: This becomes very hard to read as soon as you have `rbind(A1t, B1t, A2t, B2t, A3t)`, unless I miss something very obvious

Comment: Yes, the correct way is to not have so many objects in global environment. As you can see, it becomes very difficult to manage them. You should save them in a list.

Comment: I don't understand that latest comment. I am not working in a global environment - this is code in a function. And do you really consider five being a "so many" kind of number?

Answer (score 0):

##### `rbind(At, Bt)`

In this case you create 2 data.frames:

```
At <- data.frame(1, 2, 3)
Bt <- data.frame(c(4, 5, 6))

str(At)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ X1: num 1
 $ X2: num 2
 $ X3: num 3

str(Bt)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ c.4..5..6.: num  4 5 6
```

`rbind` requires the same columns names, also the number of columns differs.

##### `rbind(At, 4, 5, 6)`

In that case R "completes" each row repeating each number for the entire row, and giving an automatic name, e.g., `X1`. Would be the same as

```
rbind(
  At,
  c(4,4,4),
  c(5,5,5),
  c(6,6,6)
  )
```

or

```
rbind(
  At,
  data.frame(X1 = 4,X2 = 4,X3 = 4),
  data.frame(X1 = 5,X2 = 5,X3 = 5),
  data.frame(X1 = 6,X2 = 6,X3 = 6)
  )
```